# What does gcc -DPIC do?

Tags: gcc

What exactly does `-DPIC` do when compiling using GCC, and when is it really necessary?

I found that `-fpic` and `-fPIC` are to generate Position Independent Code. But I could not find anything about `-DPIC`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a preprocessor macro definition.  The GCC manual says:

> ### `-D` *`NAME`*
>
> Predefine `NAME` as a macro, with definition `1`.
>
> ## `-D` *`NAME=DEFINITION`*
>
> The contents of `DEFINITION` are tokenized and processed as if they
>   appeared during translation phase three in a `#define` directive.

This might be useful if your source code cares whether it's being compiled as position-independent code. For example:

```c
#ifdef PIC
   /* ... */
#endif
```